# .NetCore/NEST - ElasticSearch I/O issue or concurrency throttle

Tags: multithreading, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm having some issues for weeks now i can't resolve after many tries.
I have a .NET Core application which is, basically, indexing and searching documents all day.
This app allows concurrency calls to Elastic for all my use cases so when i have a big load (like 1k documents in a few seconds) i'm calling Elastic with no limits (i didn't find any limit for it, maybe i should limit threads..).
I have 2 ElasticSearch nodes on Production which have pretty good configurations for my load (according to Elastic prerequisites), 16Go RAM, 4vCPU

Sometimes, it seems that many calls are failing with that kind of error (i'm using ApplicationInsights) :

[image: AppInsights logs]

I assume NEST is doing an underlying HTTP connection to Elastic server that just timeout/failed.
When i'm looking the dependencies at the same time, i can see calls that run for over 100 000ms (but 4ms for a "normal" call)

Here an indexing example :

[image: Put example from AppInsights]

Our team checked all http route through network and we can't find any network issue.

We definitely understood it was an Elastic issue when we just restarted the Elastic services on both nodes and all started again to work.
Both nodes had a low CPU and RAM usage.
We "tried" to look at Elastic logs but we aren't very comfortable with that actually but with our "knowledge" on that we didn't find anything "unusual".

We're indexing documents one by one, never bulked. We can't change that because documents are received from an external system thanks to a ServiceBus queue and we can't control the load. So one ServiceBus message is an individual PUT call to Elastic servers.

I can't reproduce it easily to be honnest, but i would like to have some feedbacks by people using NEST/ElasticSearch and how they managed their threadPool.

Should I limit Elastic calls (using Semaphore for example) ?

Should I change Elastic server configuration ?

Please let me know if you need more information

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have monitoring on the cluster? If so, what is the load on the server (CPU, Elasticsearch threadpools) like when a SocketException is thrown? The client can also show Tcp and Threadpool stats when requests are made, which might be useful to observe too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html#_tcp_statistics

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The server didn't seem under pressure when we got this exception, that's my issue. Usually the server was the root cause but we just increased CPU and RAM few weeks ago, never seen one server on this cluster that was under pressure so far. Thanks for your link btw, if it's like DisableStreaming, i can't activate this on Production, right ? For performance issue and other stuff .. But i didn't know this option, i'll look into it. Unfortunately i can't reproduce this issue "easily"